# logging in to a joomla website, using flutter and webview

Tags: flutter, joomla

I'm building a flutter app for a website made using Joomla. I was planning to use a webview but I don't know how to implement login and register for the Joomla website, from an external php code. Login and signup authentication works but as I have said, I don't know what to do next.

I have tried to create sessions but it doesn't work

Comment: So what exactly do you expect here?

Comment: When a Person logs in through the webview, it should direct the page to the account. As the account does.

Answer (score 0):

I made a flutter app for my Joomla website. Actually my joomla website has been hacked, so I can access just to the database, so I have connected to the mySql database directly using php webservices, but I had to program everything by my own, registration, account activation, login, database searches, and so on.